# Product import csv images not getting imported

Tags: magento-1.9, database, import

I have been trying to import products CSV to my magento store.

I did import the products without the images and it was successful.

But now when I try to import the product with image column I am not able to see any images getting imported.

I tried storing the images in various places such as `"var/media/import"`, `"media/catalog/products"` and gave the path in the CSV but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create `import` directory in `media` folder and 
Put all the images in directory

> media/import

then in csv file just give only image name like `xyz.jpg`. Do not add slashes.

in csv file add image name in images columns and this column `media_gallery` also.

now try it will work.