# Importing product images in specific sequence / order

Tags: magento2, import, product-images

I import images into Magento as described here https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html and here [Product import csv images not getting imported](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190107/product-import-csv-images-not-getting-imported) :

I upload the images to `pub/media/import`, create a csv file with the skus and image filenames, and use the import functionality in Magento Admin for the csv file.

[image: CSV file format]

This works well, but the order of the images uploaded is not the way I want it to be: Alternative images are the first, and the base_image is the last in the sequence.

Our editor team is not so happy about that, because they have to manually click into each product and drag&drop the images into the correct order.

Is there any way to simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

In your csv kindly check whether the images are properly assigned to small_image,thumbnail_image,swatch_image,base_image if they are not assign them properly Hope it works.Let me know if any issues

Comment: I have updated the question and added a screenshot of the csv file. In M2 Admin, all images appear and are correctly tagged as base, thumbnail and small image, but the additional images are first in sequence.